# Installing TMUX in Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard Edition and issues with MSYS2

Tags: linux, powershell, tmux, windows-server-2016, msys2

I have a Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard Edition VM in which I need to schedule a job which should run every 3 or 5 minutes. This job actually will check for the files in Windows server location Source: ex: D:\Feeds and move the files to Linux Server Destination: /data/feeds/

1. I have installed the Git bash and scheduled a bash script to run as loop which does the job, but it's getting failed in between with the below error

   ```
        0 [main] sh 54094 dofork: child -1 - CreateProcessW failed for 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe', errno 13
   feed.sh: fork: Permission denied
   feed.sh: line 6: /usr/bin/ls: Permission denied
   ```

   I have to again the start the feed.sh script to move the files from Source (Windows server) to Destination (Linux SFTP server).
2. In order to fix this, I tried installing TMUX to schedule the script in tmux, for which I tried installing MSYS2 packages, I have installed the same but still vi, sftp commands are not working. I have tried updating the packages but getting the below timeout error.

   ```
   # pacman -S git
   resolving dependencies...
   looking for conflicting packages...

   Packages (31) expat-2.2.9-1  heimdal-7.7.0-1  openssh-8.3p1-1  perl-Authen-SASL-2.16-2  perl-Convert-BinHex-1.125-1  perl-Encode-Locale-1.05-1  perl-Error-0.17029-1
                 perl-File-Listing-6.04-2  perl-HTML-Parser-3.72-4  perl-HTML-Tagset-3.20-2  perl-HTTP-Cookies-6.08-1  perl-HTTP-Daemon-6.10-1  perl-HTTP-Date-6.05-1
                 perl-HTTP-Message-6.25-1  perl-HTTP-Negotiate-6.01-2  perl-IO-Socket-SSL-2.068-1  perl-IO-Stringy-2.113-1  perl-LWP-MediaTypes-6.04-1  perl-MIME-tools-5.509-1
                 perl-MailTools-2.21-1  perl-Net-HTTP-6.19-1  perl-Net-SMTP-SSL-1.04-1  perl-Net-SSLeay-1.88-1  perl-TermReadKey-2.38-1  perl-TimeDate-2.33-1  perl-Try-Tiny-0.30-1
                 perl-URI-1.76-1  perl-WWW-RobotRules-6.02-2  perl-libwww-6.46-1  vim-8.2.0869-1  git-2.27.0-1

   Total Download Size:   16.68 MiB
   Total Installed Size:  94.47 MiB

   :: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
   :: Retrieving packages...
   error: failed retrieving file 'expat-2.2.9-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Connection timed out after 10016 milliseconds
   error: failed retrieving file 'expat-2.2.9-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from sourceforge.net : Connection timed out after 10002 milliseconds
   ```

   Debug output:

   ```
   # pacman -Syuv --debug
   debug: pacman v5.2.1 - libalpm v12.0.1
   debug: config: attempting to read file /etc/pacman.conf
   debug: config: new section 'options'
   debug: config: HoldPkg: pacman
   debug: config: arch: x86_64
   debug: config: SigLevel: Required
   debug: config: SigLevel: DatabaseOptional
   debug: config: LocalFileSigLevel: Optional
   debug: config: new section 'mingw32'
   debug: config file /etc/pacman.conf, line 72: including /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.mingw32
   debug: config: new section 'mingw64'
   debug: config file /etc/pacman.conf, line 75: including /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.mingw64
   debug: config: new section 'msys'
   debug: config file /etc/pacman.conf, line 78: including /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.msys
   debug: config: finished parsing /etc/pacman.conf
   debug: setup_libalpm called
   debug: option 'logfile' = /var/log/pacman.log
   debug: option 'gpgdir' = /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
   debug: option 'hookdir' = /etc/pacman.d/hooks/
   debug: option 'cachedir' = /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
   debug: registering sync database 'mingw32'
   debug: database path for tree mingw32 set to /var/lib/pacman/sync/mingw32.db
   debug: GPGME version: 1.13.1-unknown
   debug: GPGME engine info: file=/usr/bin/gpg, home=/etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
   debug: checking signature for /var/lib/pacman/sync/mingw32.db
   debug: 1 signatures returned
   debug: fingerprint: AD351C50AE085775EB59333B5F92EFC1A47D45A1
   debug: summary: valid
   debug: summary: green
   debug: status: Success
   debug: timestamp: 1593429151
   debug: exp_timestamp: 0
   debug: validity: full; reason: Success
   debug: key: AD351C50AE085775EB59333B5F92EFC1A47D45A1, Alexey Pavlov (Alexpux) <alexpux@gmail.com>, owner_trust unknown, disabled 0
   debug: signature is valid
   debug: signature is fully trusted
   debug: setting usage of 15 for mingw32 repository
   debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/i686
   debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/files/REPOS/MINGW/i686
   debug: registering sync database 'mingw64'
   debug: database path for tree mingw64 set to /var/lib/pacman/sync/mingw64.db
   debug: checking signature for /var/lib/pacman/sync/mingw64.db
   debug: 1 signatures returned
   debug: fingerprint: AD351C50AE085775EB59333B5F92EFC1A47D45A1
   debug: summary: valid
   debug: summary: green
   debug: status: Success
   debug: timestamp: 1593425462
   debug: exp_timestamp: 0
   debug: validity: full; reason: Success
   debug: key: AD351C50AE085775EB59333B5F92EFC1A47D45A1, Alexey Pavlov (Alexpux) <alexpux@gmail.com>, owner_trust unknown, disabled 0
   debug: signature is valid
   debug: signature is fully trusted
   debug: setting usage of 15 for mingw64 repository
   debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/x86_64
   debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/files/REPOS/MINGW/x86_64
   Root      : /
   Conf File : /etc/pacman.conf
   DB Path   : /var/lib/pacman/
   Cache Dirs: /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
   Hook Dirs : /usr/share/libalpm/hooks/  /etc/pacman.d/hooks/
   Lock File : /var/lib/pacman/db.lck
   Log File  : /var/log/pacman.log
   GPG Dir   : /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
   Targets   : None
   :: Synchronizing package databases...
   debug: url: http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/i686/mingw32.db
   debug: maxsize: 26214400
   debug: using time condition: 1593429151
   debug: opened tempfile for download: /var/lib/pacman/sync/mingw32.db.part (wb)
   debug: curl returned error 28 from transfer
   error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from repo.msys2.org : Connection timed out after 10018 milliseconds
   debug: url: https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/files/REPOS/MINGW/i686/mingw32.db
   debug: maxsize: 26214400
   debug: using time condition: 1593429151
   debug: opened tempfile for download: /var/lib/pacman/sync/mingw32.db.part (wb)
   debug: curl returned error 28 from transfer
   error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from sourceforge.net : Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds
   ```

3. Is there any other way to schedule the bash script in powershell?